# Function keys on t450s always active

Tags: release-freya, system, keyboard

It seems all the function keys are active by default on my lenovo t450s with elementary OS Freya. E.g. <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> control screen brightness on press. Usually I have to hold or hit the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key first.

Does anyone know how I can get the original functionality back of using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to toggle the function keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually a BIOS setting. If there is nothing in there (perhaps it is [set to Ctrl](https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t450s/documents/HT074187?tabName=Solutions) rather than Fn), you could try pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to toggle *FnLock* as is [reported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91616/does-the-fn-lock-fnlk-on-thinkpad-t440s-work-well-with-linux) to work on earlier Thinkpad models.

Comment: Fn + Esc worked like a charm. I completely overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the BIOS setting, then you can still use Fn+ESC to toggle the opposite.

But if you always depend on Fn+ESC, sometimes you'll forget to enable it when you start up, and plus the green LED will over time Dim and consume a small amount of extra energy... for no real reason.